# Dead tab button in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 on a macbook pro (bootcamp). Im unfortunately not sure what caused this, but i have managed to kill my tab button. I am no longer able to indent code, autocomplete or insert snippets using it. It works perfectly fine in other applications, though. I do not use ReSharper.

Restart Visual Studio did not work.
Starting Visual Studio with "devenv /safemode" did not work.
Tab is also dead in other solutions/projects.
Reboot did not work.

This is very strange, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try Tools -> Options -> Text Editor ... choose your language of choice then click `Tabs` and make sure it's set to the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the key-bindings via:

*Tools* => *Options* => *Environment* => *Keyboard* => *Reset*